AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'end_stop'
For a school project we have to make a working rail-road system. One part of the system is a Board_passengers function. I have the following Classes:
class Station:
  def __init__(self, name, number_of_tracks):
    self.name = name
    self.number_of_tracks = number_of_tracks
    self.waiting_pass = []

  def __str__(self):
    return(f"Station {self.name} has {self.number_of_tracks} tracks. The passengers waiting are {self.waiting_pass}")

  def set_waiting_passengers(self, waiting_passengers):
    self.waiting_pass = [waiting_passengers]

class Centraal(Station):
  def __init__(self, name, list_of_stores):
    self.name = name
    self.number_of_tracks = 10
    self.waiting_pass = []
    self.list_of_stores = list_of_stores

  def add_store(self, store):
    self.list_of_stores.append(store)

  def remove_store(self, store):
    if store in self.list_of_stores:
      self.list_of_stores.remove(store)

class Passenger:
  def __init__(self, name, start_stop, end_stop):
    self.name = name
    self.start_stop = start_stop
    self.end_stop = end_stop
    self.has_arrived = False



  def arrived(self):
   self.has_arrived = True

  def __repr__(self):
    travel_str = "travelled" if self.has_arrived else "travels"
    return f"{self.name} {travel_str} from {self.start_stop} to {self.end_stop}"

class Train:
  def __init__(self, num_train_parts, capacity, speed, route):
    self.num_train_parts = num_train_parts
    self.capacity = capacity
    self.speed = speed
    self.route = route
    self.current_stop_index = 0
    self.current_stop = self.route[self.current_stop_index]
    self.passengers = []

  def get_current_stop(self):
    return self.current_stop

  def go_next_stop(self):
    if self.current_stop_index < len(self.route) -1:
      self.current_stop_index += 1
      self.current_stop = self.route[self.current_stop_index]
    else:
      print("This is the last stop on the route")

  def set_passengers(self, passengers):
    self.passengers = passengers

  def board_passengers(self):
    current_stop = self.get_current_stop()
    waiting_passengers = current_stop.waiting_pass.copy()
    for passenger in waiting_passengers:
      if len(self.passengers) < self.capacity:
        if passenger.end_stop in self.route:
          self.passengers.append(passenger)
          current_stop.waiting_pass.remove(passenger)
      else:
        break

  def unboard_passengers(self):
    current_stop = self.get_current_stop()
    remaining_passengers = self.passengers.copy()
    for passenger in remaining_passengers:
      if passenger.end_stop == current_stop.name:
        self.passengers.remove(passenger)

I also made a list of passengers as follows:
list_of_passengers = []

for id in range(10):
    passenger = Passenger(id, station_r_c, station_r_a)
    list_of_passengers.append(passenger)

station_r_c.set_waiting_passengers([passenger.name for passenger in list_of_passengers])

And I made some stations:
station_r_a = Station("Rotterdam Alexander", 2)
station_r_c = Centraal("Rotterdam Centraal", ['Hema', 'AH to go', 'Dudok'])

Now, when I run the following code, actually running the board.passengers function:
train1 = Train(2, 10, 120, [station_r_c, station_r_a])

train1.board_passengers()

I get the output and error message:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-fe56f8ef609b> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 train1 = Train(2, 10, 120, [station_r_c, station_r_a])
      3 
----> 4 train1.board_passengers()

<ipython-input-53-6cf34d8258f3> in board_passengers(self)
     28     for passenger in waiting_passengers:
     29       if len(self.passengers) < self.capacity:
---> 30         if passenger.end_stop in self.route:
     31           self.passengers.append(passenger)
     32           current_stop.waiting_pass.remove(passenger)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'end_stop'

I've tried everything but I can't work out why Python has such a problem with getting the end_stop from the passengers. Can anyone help me out?

The waiting passengers at each stop should be a list rather than a list of lists.
Change:
def set_waiting_passengers(self, waiting_passengers):
    self.waiting_pass = [waiting_passengers]

to:
def set_waiting_passengers(self, waiting_passengers):
    self.waiting_pass = waiting_passengers


This makes sense, I changed it but now the error changed to: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'end_stop'.

The simplest solution to your problem is to change this line:
station_r_c.set_waiting_passengers([passenger.name for passenger in list_of_passengers])

to this:
station_r_c.set_waiting_passengers(list_of_passengers)

The problem you have is that you are passing only a list of ids to your function.
You will need to change
def __str__(self):
    return(f"Station {self.name} has {self.number_of_tracks} tracks. The passengers waiting are {self.waiting_pass}")

if you take my solution. But here you can simply use the list comprehension you were using before.
